# Html file turned into a series of binary 00, how to change it back

Tags: html, windows, atom-editor

Recently i was working on one of my projects in the atom editor and modifying some of the HTML code. When I was working on this my laptop shut down instantly with no warning message and the screen just went blank. When I turned on my machine again and went to the HTML file I was working on I saw nothing in it is markup, and when I tried to open it in sublime text 3 it displayed a series of binary 00's, when I checked the file size it shows the exact same file size of 15.6kb as earlier so I'm guessing that the data has got lost in some kind of machine translation, I'm running on windows 8 and haven't got system protection turned on, i have also lost my copy of the backup (bac. I have no idea why this occurred and haven't found any solution to fix this, please it's really important that I recover my HTML markup again, thanks for your help in advance.

The link to the file:-
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3OjkFjnRRjtbWhwcHJsSDZYNVE

Comment: Are you using any kind of version control, like git? You can just pull the branch from remote or roll back to the latest commit if that's the case. If you don't... Now you know why version control can be very useful.

Comment: Don't Atom have any kind of history of files? Yet another reason why you use plain text-editors, like Sublime. Also, no backup? Rewrite the HTML. It's an HTML-file. It shouldn't take that long.

Comment: No, unfortunately, I'm not used to any version controlling systems, I am used to backing up, but you're correct. I should start using VCS more. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie, unfortunately, that comes as a package and I haven't installed it yet, usually, I use sublime but I was interested in using atom due to its features. But I am guessing I should have been a bit more careful and the backup got deleted on the server I was using (unrecoverable).

Comment: What features, if I may ask?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Well the main functionality I wanted was this https://atom.io/packages/atom-html-preview I used to work with WebStorm before and they had this by default, but now I have to implicitly add this feature in a painstaking way so instead I shifted to Atom because of this, you see as a designer it saves a lot of time for me from pressing ALT+TAB and F5 every time I do a change and just see it happen automatically during a change. So simply, a live preview of the code.

Comment: BTW I'm writing the code slowly and weakly as of now and am approaching to the previous state of it, FYI. But still, I would like to know why this happened and how I can prevent it. I've grown fond of ATOM but if it continues to perform in this way I'll have to abandon it, I guess.

Comment: Ah. That's a completely (well, mostly) useless function. It will never be able to provide previews for more than at best one rendering engine, and that's no good, when you have to test in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Opera at least, and on both OS X and Windows at a minimum. I would just run Firefox and Chrome on a separate screen and have a script refresh the page every 20 seconds or something :-)

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie yeah I'm usually used to BrowserSync on Node.js but haven't found a way to use this on PHP which this project is built on, unfortunately, i haven't found a solution for this yet for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure this is a real answer, But you can maybe copy and paste the gibberish Binary into a translator and get back your text. It probably won't be formatted but I hope you get your project back!

http://binarytranslator.com/

And many Others

Comment: Hi, first of all, thank you for your response, but unfortunately, that is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried some recovery tools like easy recovery. I'm not sure about it, but it helped me several times when I had such kind of situations.

Comment: Yeah, I've used Recuva on deep scan for the entire drive. But still no luck, thanks anyway. :)